# Still can't find largest number in binary tree

Tags: c++, binary-tree

I still can't find the largest number in my tree, but now I am really not complicating it, I think it should work, there is no error, but it just won't show me in the console.  Anyone got an idea?  I am getting really frustrated.

Here is my entire code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib> 


using namespace std;


template<class T>
class BinaryTree
{

struct Node
    {
        T data;
        Node* lChildptr;
        Node* rChildptr;

        Node(T dataNew)
        {
            data = dataNew;
            lChildptr = NULL;
            rChildptr = NULL;

        }
    };
private:
    Node* root; 

        void Insert(T newData, Node* &theRoot)
        {
            if(theRoot == NULL) 
            {
                theRoot = new Node(newData);
                return;
            }

            if(newData < theRoot->data)  
                Insert(newData, theRoot->lChildptr);
            else
                Insert(newData, theRoot->rChildptr);;
        }

        void PrintTree(Node* theRoot)
        {
            if(theRoot != NULL)
            {
                PrintTree(theRoot->lChildptr);
                cout<< theRoot->data<<" \n";;
                PrintTree(theRoot->rChildptr);
            }
        }
T Largest( Node* theRoot)
{
    if ( root == NULL ){
    cout<<"There is no tree";
    return -1;
    }

    if (theRoot->rChildptr != NULL)
        return Largest(theRoot->rChildptr);
    else
        return theRoot->data;
        cout<<theRoot->data;


}; 

    public:
        BinaryTree()
        {
            root = NULL;
        }

        void AddItem(T newData)
        {
            Insert(newData, root);
        }

        void PrintTree()
        {
            PrintTree(root);
        }
        T Largest()
        {
            return Largest(root);
        }
    };

    int main()
    {

        BinaryTree<int> *myBT = new BinaryTree<int>();
        myBT->AddItem(2);
        myBT->AddItem(5);
        myBT->AddItem(1);
        myBT->AddItem(10);
        myBT->AddItem(15);
        myBT->PrintTree();
        myBT->Largest();

    }
```

and here is the part that is supposed to find the largest number (the child that is far right down):

```
T Largest( Node* theRoot)
{
    if ( root == NULL ){
    cout<<"There is no tree";
    return -1;
    }

    if (theRoot->rChildptr != NULL)
        return Largest(theRoot->rChildptr);
    else
        return theRoot->data;
    cout<<theRoot->data;

};
```

Comment: did you step through the code in the debugger?

Comment: not sure, how to use the debugger, where should i set the breakpoint?

Comment: What problems are you having? What's the error?

Comment: nothing nothing, its fine now, the answer is down below. Thx everyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems in your code in `Largest()`:

- It looks like you wanted to execute two statements in the else clause, but you didn't use braces.
- You wanted to execute the cout print after returning, which is impossible. Switch the order around.

So you should replace your fragment of code with this:

```
    else {
        cout << theRoot->data;
        return theRoot->data;
    }
```

Incidentally, don't let double semicolons (`;;`) stay in your code. It's harmless in most cases, but it's always bad style.

Comment: i have braces now, but still nothing, removed the double semicolons to.

Comment: I just came back to say i finally found the problem that i just the to switch the cout and the return, and then i saw that u wrote it, to thx a lot thought, could you explain me why this works now after switch, im not sure.. :D

Comment: Because return means "get out of this function **right now** and give the value back to the caller".

Comment: In some languages like Java, it's a serious error to put any statement after a return, so your mistake could have been caught easily.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a fixed and slightly cleaned-up version that works:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib> 

using namespace std;

template<class T>
class BinaryTree
{
    struct Node
    {
        T data;
        Node* lChildptr;
        Node* rChildptr;

        Node(T dataNew)
        {
            data = dataNew;
            lChildptr = 0;
            rChildptr = 0;
        }
    };

private:

    Node* root;

    void Insert(T newData, Node** theRoot)
    {
        if (*theRoot == 0)
        {
            *theRoot = new Node(newData);
        }
        else if (newData < (*theRoot)->data)
            Insert(newData, &((*theRoot)->lChildptr));
        else
            Insert(newData, &((*theRoot)->rChildptr));
    }

    void PrintTree(Node* theRoot)
    {
        if (theRoot != 0)
        {
            PrintTree(theRoot->lChildptr);
            cout << theRoot->data << " " << endl;
            PrintTree(theRoot->rChildptr);
        }
    }

    T Largest(Node* theRoot)
    {
        if (root == 0)
        {
          throw "There is no tree";
        }

        if (theRoot->rChildptr != 0)
            return Largest(theRoot->rChildptr);
        else
            return theRoot->data;
    }

public:

    BinaryTree()
    {
        root = 0;
    }

    void AddItem(T newData)
    {
        Insert(newData, &root);
    }

    void PrintTree()
    {
        PrintTree(root);
    }

    T Largest()
    {
        return Largest(root);
    }
};

int main()
{
    BinaryTree<int> *myBT = new BinaryTree<int>();

    cout << "The tree is empty. Trying to find the largest element." << endl;

    try
    {
      cout << "Largest element: " << myBT->Largest() << endl;
    }
    catch (const char* e)
    {
      cout << "Exception caught: " << e << endl;
    }

    myBT->AddItem(15);
    myBT->AddItem(2);
    myBT->AddItem(5);
    myBT->AddItem(1);
    myBT->AddItem(10);

    cout << "Tree:" << endl;
    myBT->PrintTree();

    cout << "Largest element: " << myBT->Largest() << endl;
}
```

Output:

```
The tree is empty. Trying to find the largest element.
Exception caught: There is no tree
Tree:
1
2
5
10
15
Largest element: 15
```

Comment: thank you, yes it looks cleaner,there is a lot things to learn and my style needs a lot improvement to, even if i think that i dont have a style yet.